# MySQL Data Adapter ver 6.1.3.0 not returning ID when ver 5 data adapter did work

Tags: c#, mysql

I recently upgraded my MySQL data adapter from v5 to v6. When I use the v5 MySQL Data Adapter this code below worked perfectly. However since I have begun using v6 of the data adapter, when I add a new record, it does not return the "new" ID of the record. Does anyone know an elegant way to achieve this?

```
protected void SetRecord(ref T Data, string Sql)
    {
        //
        // Get a connection to use
        //
        string connectionKey = "";
        MySqlConnection Connection = ConnectionManager.Current.OpenConnection(out connectionKey);

        MySqlDataAdapter da;
        MySqlCommandBuilder cb;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr;

        da = new MySqlDataAdapter(Sql, Connection);
        da.Fill(dt);
        //
        // If there is more than one row, then edit 1st row, else add new row
        //
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            dr = dt.Rows[0];
            DatabaseRow_Set(ref dr, Data);

            //
            // Update the DataSet with the Database
            //
            cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);
            da.Update(dt);

        }
        else
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            DatabaseRow_Set(ref dr, Data);
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            //
            // Update the DataSet with the Database
            //
            cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);
            da.Update(dt);

            //
            // Call get from data row to get new ID
            //
            DatabaseRow_Get(dr, ref Data);
        }

        //
        // Close Connection
        //
        ConnectionManager.Current.CloseConnection(connectionKey);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant find out why this functionality worked in v5 and is now not working in v6. However, I did find a workaround.

```
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                DatabaseRow_Set(ref dr, Data);
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);                
                //
                // Update the DataSet with the Database
                //
                cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder da);                                                
                da.Update(dt);                

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select LAST_INSERT_ID()", Connection);
                long ID = ((long) cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                DatabaseRow_GetID(ref Data, ID);
```